# Real vs Complex Dimension are different?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Okay if $C$ is a complex vector space, (say with n dimensions) then if we consider $C_\mathbb{R}$ to be the same vector space except all scalar combinations are real valued vs complex. Why does a basis for $C_\mathbb{R}$ have 2n dimensions?

It’s still the same space with a restriction on the scalar multiples it is closed under.

Comment: $n$ real parts plus $n$ complex parts gives $2n$ real numbers. For example, $\mathbb{C}$ has complex dimension $1$ and real dimension $2.$

Answer (score 1):

It's "the same" space in some sense, but when you have *fewer* scalars to pick from, it is *harder* to make a linear combination, and therefore *harder* for a set of vectors to be linearly *dependent*.

Conversely, this makes it *easier* for a set of vectors to be *independent*, so it should not be surprising that you can have *larger* independent sets when you use a *smaller* scalar field.

Answer (score 0):

The natural map $\Bbb R^2 \to\Bbb C, \ (x, y) \mapsto x+iy$ is an $\Bbb R$-linear isomorphism, hence $\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R$ vector spaces, and $\dim_{\Bbb R}\Bbb C=2$, and
$$\Bbb C^n\cong(\Bbb R^2)^n\cong\Bbb R^{2n}$$
over $\Bbb R$.

From the other view point, we cannot introduce multiplication with *any complex* number on an odd dimensional real vector space; in particular the natural multiplication by a complex number *leads out* of the one dimensional $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of a vector space is basically the minimal number of basis vectors you need in order to span any vector you want, using vector addition and scalar multiplication.
To make things simple, let's look at $\Bbb C^3$ (although the same reasoning applies to any dimension).

If your space is over $\Bbb C$, what are your basis vectors? The usual choice would be $(1, 0, 0) , (0, 1, 0) , (0, 0, 1)$. Using scalar multiplication and vector addition, you can use these 3 vectors to span any vector in $\Bbb C^3$; If you want to express $(a+bi, c+di, e+fi)$ you can just use the linear combination $(a+bi)\cdot (1,0,0)+(c+di)\cdot (0,1,0)+(e+fi)\cdot (0,0,1)$.

But if you're over $\Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb C$, you can't do that - you can only multiplies by real scalars. This means 3 basis vectors are just not enough - you need the basis $(1, 0, 0) , (0, 1, 0) , (0, 0, 1), (i,0,0), (0,i,0), (0,0,i)$ in order to span any vector using linear combinations of the basis vectors.

It's easy to understand if you think of the complex plane - you can't describe a number using only 1 coordiate - you need 2. The same goes for $\Bbb C^n$ for any $n$ - you need twice the information.

Comment: I assume the "2" comes from the fact that a scalar in C is a "vector" dot product with (1,i)?  How would you prove that an n-dimensional complex vector space has 2n dimensions when realized as a real space?  

Thanks for the help!

Comment: An n-dimensional complex vector is basically an ordered list of n complex numbers, so the explanation is basically the same as for the example given above. Just like you can't express an arbitrary complex number with only one real number, but only with two (because each complex number has independent real and imaginary parts), the same goes for n numbers - each one requires 2 bits of information, over all giving 2n degrees of freedom.

Comment: This is of course an explanation and not a genuine proof. If you're looking for a proof, the comment by Berci gives the general idea. But I think it's more important to understand why exactly that is the case :)